# Overflow hidden causes subgrid to break on mobile

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, overflow, css-grid

I have an incredibly frustrating issue, regarding CSS grids, the `overflow` keyword, and mobile development.

I am using Javascript to toggle `overflow: hidden` on a container element, which happens to have `display: grid` and `grid-template-columns: subgrid`.

This works fine on my desktop, but I have tested on my iPhone 12 (iOS 16.1.2), both using Safari and Firefox, and the browser collapses all of the grid columns into one when the container's overflow property is set to `hidden`.

This was tested using alerts, and displaying the computed `grid-template-columns` value for the container before and after using Javascript to set `container.style.overflow = hidden;`, which on desktop displays `Columns: 5` before and `Columns: 5` after, while on mobile it shows `Columns: 5` before and `Columns: 1` after.

I have also tested this without using the `subgrid` keyword, and it works. The columns don't rearrange when using an explicitly defined grid, but this doesn't achieve what I'm looking for.

Does anyone have any experience with subgrids and overflow issues on mobile?

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to show some code here. Please create a snippet demo using the editor.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example should help you create a runnable snippet which will be within your question - please check that it does indeed show the problem. What browser are you using on your desktop?